# Regex for matching a mix of delimited tokens and email address

Tags: regex, string, validation, composite

I need to validate a string for valid email addresses or specific tokens (later to be replaced by email addresses) or a mix of both delimited by semi-colon. I need a little help with this regex I nearly got working.
It matches the tokens but not the email address at the start or end.

`^(((<#a#>)+|[;])*|(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*|((<#a#>)+|[;])*)$`

Comment: Some test data would be nice. Have you seen http://regex101.com? On that site, you can test regexes interactively.

Comment: Here are some strings:
1 <#a#>;<#a#>;<#a#>
2 a@b.com;<#a#>;<#a#>
3 <#a#>;<#a#>;a@b.com
a@b.com;<#a#>;a@b.com

Comment: In addition to @TimPietzcker, [regex buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is worth looking into.

Comment: I think I got it working by removing the alteration `(|)` symbol between the groups. Here is the version that is matching all my test data
`(((<#a#>)+|[;])*((([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*)*((<#a#>)+|[;])*)*`

Comment: Try also this `^((<#a#>)+|[;]|(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)+$` [See here](https://regex101.com/r/aU3uL7/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer posted by AlexBay which is working with my test data.

`^((<#a#>)+|[;]|(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})‌​+)+$`